# In PHP how to use simple if statement inside td tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

My PHP script has the following if statement:

```
if($idx = strripos($output,','))//Get the last index of ',' in your output string
{
 $ErrorCode = substr($output,$idx + 1,(strlen($output) - $idx) - 1); 
 //$Playlist = substr($output, 0, $idx + 1); //Get the rest of the output string, minus the error code 
 echo " " .$Playlist.ReturnError($ErrorCode); //The ReturnError function just replaces the error code with a custom error
```

How can I use the if statement inside the last td tag:

```
//php script continued..

echo '<table style="width:50%">
<tr>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Date/Time</th>
<th>Playing</th>
<th>Error</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>Test</td>
<td>'.$array[0].'</td>
<td>'.$array[1].'</td>
<td></td>
</tr>

</table>';
```

I have looked at various examples on other posts but I can't figure out how to get it working.

Comment: Do you know what a ternary operator is?

Comment: No, I do not? But I will look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//php script continued..

echo '<table style="width:50%">
<tr>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Date/Time</th>
<th>Playing</th>
<th>Error</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>Test</td>
<td>'.$array[0].'</td>
<td>'.$array[1].'</td>
<td>';
if($idx = strripos($output,','))//Get the last index of ',' in your output string
{
 $ErrorCode = substr($output,$idx + 1,(strlen($output) - $idx) - 1); 
 //$Playlist = substr($output, 0, $idx + 1); //Get the rest of the output string, minus the error code 
 echo " " .$Playlist.ReturnError($ErrorCode); //The ReturnError function just replaces the error code with a custom error
}

echo'</td>
</tr>

</table>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options

Ternary Operator http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

```
echo('<h1>' . isset($array[0]) ? $array[0] : 'default' . '</h1>');
```

Null Coalescing Operator (php 7 only) http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce

```
echo('<h1>' . $array[0] ?? 'default' . '</h1>');
```

In the position of `defaullt` you could do everything you want like invoking a method, displaying an error message etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response, although I have accepted an answer from another user but after looking into the use of ternary operators, I think this may help me with another issue that I'm trying to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this

//php script continued..

$str='<table style="width:50%">
<tr>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Date/Time</th>
<th>Playing</th>
<th>Error</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>Test</td>
<td>'.$array[0].'</td>
<td>'.$array[1].'</td>
<td>';
if($idx = strripos($output,','))//Get the last index of ',' in your output string
{
 $ErrorCode = substr($output,$idx + 1,(strlen($output) - $idx) - 1); 
 //$Playlist = substr($output, 0, $idx + 1); //Get the rest of the output string, minus the error code 
 $str.= " " .$Playlist.ReturnError($ErrorCode); //The ReturnError function just replaces the error code with a custom error

}

$str.='</td>
</tr>

</table>';
```